# Show view only when data is received from API

Tags: ios, ios7, view

I am new to iOS development and one thing that I am finding bad with good UX is following.

I have a view that looks like when View loads.

[image]

But behind the scenes an `API` call gets the data and calls `tableView.reloadData` which fills in all the data.

**Problems**
1. I want to only show the view when populated. meaning when `API` returns result and populates labels.
2. While 1. is getting worked upon, I want to show an activity indicator letting user know that we are working on getting the data.

How could this be achieved? I don't know what to search specifically for that.

Answer (score 1):

You need an asynchronous request with a completion block/closure.

Look into Alamofire if you're using Swift, or AFNetworking if you're using Objective-C.

In Swift, you'd do something like:

```
// Start animating some spinning wheel here
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
         .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                     // Stop animating spinning wheel and call reloadData here
                   }
```

In Objective-C, that'd be something like:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
// Start animating some spinning wheel here
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Stop animating spinning wheel and call reloadData here
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Cheers!